# Morphing images using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, html5-canvas, javascript

Is there any jQuery or Canvas code for a morphing animation from one image to another. I'm in need of this. I searched a lot but stood with null result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want a pure canvas solution you can use opacity (alpha) to achieve your effect:**

- Start with 2 images on top of each other,
- Begin with image#1 being fully opaque and image#2 being fully transparent,
- In an animation loop, slowly reduce the opacity of image#1 and increase the opacity of image#2,
- You can set the opacity (alpha) of an image drawn in canvas using: `context.globalAlpha`.

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
$("#fade").hide();

var imageURLs=[];  // put the paths to your images here
var imagesOK=0;
var imgs=[];
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-1.jpg");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-2.jpg");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-3.jpg");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-4.jpg");
loadAllImages();
//
function loadAllImages(){
  for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    imgs.push(img);
    img.onload = function(){ 
      imagesOK++; 
      if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
        $("#fade").show();
        ctx.drawImage(imgs[0],0,0);
      }
    };
    img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.src = imageURLs[i];
  }      
}


var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var fadeOutIndex=imgs.length-1;
var fadeInIndex=0;
var fadePct=0;

function animateFade(){
  if(fadePct>100){return;}
  requestAnimationFrame(animateFade);
  draw(imgs[fadeInIndex],fadePct/100);
  draw(imgs[fadeOutIndex],(1-fadePct/100));
  fadePct++;
}

function draw(img,opacity){
  ctx.save();
  ctx.globalAlpha=opacity;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  ctx.restore();
}

$("#fade").click(function(){
  fadePct=0;
  if(++fadeOutIndex == imgs.length){fadeOutIndex=0;}
  if(++fadeInIndex == imgs.length){fadeInIndex=0;}
  animateFade();
});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="fade">Fade to next Image</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=204 height=204></canvas><br>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur code. I'm expecting this but with better animations. I will take care of that thanks..

Answer (score 2):

I used this plugin on many projects and I think you should take a look at it : http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

You would be looking at the fade option

Here is the library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
```

Here is an example :

```
$('#fade').cycle();
```

And the html

```
<div class="pics" id="fade">
        <img width="200" height="200" src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach1.jpg" >
        <img width="200" height="200" src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach2.jpg" >
        <img width="200" height="200" src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach3.jpg">
    </div>
```

Comment: Nice, that's a well-written and flexible transition library!

Comment: I agree, I added some examples to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks 4 ur Suggesstion. I will try out this..